# how to validate the json request of rest service

Tags: spring-boot, validation

I need to write a code in which i need to validate the tag and the value of the tag in java, spring boot project:

Request:
{
  "recipientType": "individual",
  "templateId": "acb",
  "to": "9999999999"
}

if I will remove templateId tag from the request itself.
Code should through error description: template id is missing

How can I implement this validation in java spring boot project

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of Bean Validation support in Spring to validate the contents of request body.

Here is a nice tutorial explain bean validation in detail.
https://reflectoring.io/bean-validation-with-spring-boot/